# How do I point a domain name to a Django url?

Tags: django, apache, url

I have a subdomain `m.example.com` that I want to point to the same location as `example.com/mobile` running on an apache2/django1.3 installation.

`example.com` is the landing page, and I have the `urls.py` configured such that urls that match `/^mobile$/` will be served the mobile version of the page. I looked into `<VirtualHost>`, but I think it requires a physical location for me to point `m.example.com` at and with the django urls there is no physical location except for the root of the project directory.

I am unsure if the configuration change is made on the apache side or the django side.

I've also looked into the `mod_rewrite` module for Apache, but I would prefer if I didnt have to redirect `m.example.com` to `example.com/mobile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will avoid apache redirections, just using Middlewares.

It's common to use a middleware to get a context variable that gives the current domain that the user is using.

From: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1119/

```
class SubdomainMiddleware:
    """ Make the subdomain publicly available to classes """

    def process_request(self, request):
        domain_parts = request.get_host().split('.')
        if (len(domain_parts) > 2):
            subdomain = domain_parts[0]
            if (subdomain.lower() == 'www'):
                subdomain = None
            domain = '.'.join(domain_parts[1:])
        else:
            subdomain = None
            domain = request.get_host()

        request.subdomain = subdomain
        request.domain = domain
```

on your view, can use the subdomain and domain value to properly switch content and logic.

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.subdomain == 'm':
         return movil_homepage(request)
    else:
         return default_homepage(request)
```

You can even get decorators, and map all the views on your website.

Even more common, it's just to build a second project, that use the same database. It's up to you.

Comment: Thank-you for pointing me in the right direction. In the end, I wrote a middleware that rewrote request.path_info. I did find a more well rounded solution on github: https://github.com/tkaemming/django-subdomains

Answer (score 1):

Although you could proxy `m.example.com` to `example.com/mobile`, that will cause your `reverse` and `url` functions to break.

So the only proper way to fix this is by creating an extra `<VirtualHost>` that uses `^$` for your mobile urls.